# how to receive contentXml values in xml format in solr Apache?

Tags: sdl-tridion, solr

When we send a query to get the information about a component which has ContentXml from apache solr we got the result as a string value

```
  <result name="response" numFound="1" start="0"> 
   <doc> 
    <str name="ContentXml"> RecommendedHotels xmlns uuid:fef103a8-f01e-451d-8f37-8e41124473e8 
        city href tcm:4-16808-1024 title cityTitle xlink http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink test city
        RecommendedHotels
     </str> 
    </doc>
   </result>
```

contentxml in tridion:

```
<RecommendedHotels xmlns="uuid:fef103a8-f01e-451d-8f37-8e41124473e8">
  <city xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:1-1111-1024" xlink:title="city title">test</city>
</RecommendedHotels>
```

In solr apache schema.xml we have type as text.

```
<field name="contentXml" type="text" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Is there any method that we can get the raw value of contentxml?

Comment: Which API are you using to query information? You should be able to get any item by TCM URI over TOM.NET or the Core Service, right?

Comment: Yes we can use Core Service to get the information as in Tiridion but we want to use Solr instead of core Service client  we just sent the query to localhost:8983/tridion/select?q=Id%3A\4\-1234&wt=xml&indent=true

Comment: Solr handle indexing and searching for the CM, though I don't believe it's a supported way to retrieve content, which should be done via APIs or UIs. I see you have another question on how to change what's indexed, which might get you what you're looking for.

I'm not saying this isn't possible, but the risk here is if, or when, the product changes its underlying search engine, your integration will need a rewrite.

What are you trying to solve or achieve as there might be better approaches for such an integration? Are you specifically checking what's indexed?